# Outlook.com import emails with large attachments

Tags: outlook.com, onedrive

Is there any way I can get around the 10MB limit?

Using the "Add Send/Receive Account" import method seems to just ignore them, and "copy to folder" using an email client (Windows Live Mail) fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the [Mail Migration add-on](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/outlook/import-desktop-app) will do the trick (requires IE).

1. Setup your existing email account with Outlook Express, Windows Live Mail or Windows Mail.
2. Send/Receive to download your messages
3. Sign-in to your Outlook.com in IE & [run the tool](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=254689).

Just tested with a ~20MB attachment and all was good.